# Why is Multisim Oscilloscope ALWAYS doubling my input voltage?

Tags: oscilloscope

My Multisim Oscilloscope is ALWAYS doubling my input voltage.

If I put a 5Vp in from the function generator, it will show a sine wave with a 10Vp in the scope.

This is extremely frustrating and I would appreciate any help. Here is a screenshot:

[image: This is the scope showing 5V/div - you can see it reaching two division, i.e. 10Vp]

*Figure 1: This is the scope showing 5V/div - you can see it reaching two division, i.e. 10Vp*

Comment: Try connecting to COM of signal generator instead of -

Comment: Does Multisim model the output impedance of the signal generator and input impedance of the oscilloscope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connection to function generator should be to COM (common/ground) instead of negative. Also add a ground point for good practice.
Try that.

'-' connection is used for phase inversion

Comment: Many thanks, that solved it!